# Email SSMS Log Shipping Status Report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, log-shipping

We use Log Shipping to allow Business Analysis users to query data. I would like to email the Log Shipping Status report to users to see last time data is refreshed.

When I Right Click on `Server--> Standard reports -->` It says members of the SysAdmin Report can only view this.

How can I give access, or email Report Status to Users of the report? I prefer to keep the same color html format if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule below SQL to run daily with a SQL Agent job or if you have SSRS you can easily schedule and format the report. It will give you most of the information from the standard reports.

```
select ls.primary_server,ls.primary_database,lsd.restore_delay,
DATEDIFF(mi,lms.last_restored_date,getdate()) as time_since_last_restore,
lms.last_copied_date,lms.last_restored_date,lms.last_copied_file,
lms.last_restored_file,
lsd.disconnect_users,ls.backup_source_directory,
ls.backup_destination_directory,ls.monitor_server


from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_secondary ls
join msdb.dbo.log_shipping_secondary_databases lsd
  on lsd.secondary_id=ls.secondary_id
join msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_secondary lms
  on lms.secondary_id=lsd.secondary_id
```

For HTML email status report use this answer:  [**Here's how can you create the HTML body part of your mail**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83776/need-to-send-a-formatted-html-email-via-database-mail-in-sql-server-2008-r2)